# I need help making a trigger in mysql that prevents/alerts when having the same Car_Plate more than once in the table

Tags: mysql, trigger

[image]
I need help making a trigger in mysql that prevents/alerts when having the same Car_Plate more than once in the table

Comment: what trigger have you tried and what was the error/incorrect result? (Note SO is a help site, not do your homework site).

Answer (score 1):

A unique index on that field will prevent duplicate insertions:

```
ALTER TABLE car_rentals
ADD UNIQUE KEY (Car_Plate)
```

Comment: Except that is not the homework assignment, the OP needs to make a trigger when it happens.

Comment: And now the OP has learnt that sometimes homework questions aren't sane. Anyway, if they want a trigger they can try to do it themselves.

Comment: If there is some _other_ use for the Trigger, then we might discuss it further.